# Would the City Hunter manga not be exported anymore?

Tags: manga-production, city-hunter

I've read the city hunter manga, which has about 193 chapters. But there are only 136 chapters available in my *country*. Did they stop translation and distribution of the rest of the chapters in foreign countries?

Comment: available where?

Answer (score 1):

[*City Hunter* on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/City_Hunter) says there are 35 Volumes to the series originally running in Japan from 1985 to 1991/1992.

on the [List of Chapters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_City_Hunter_chapters) the final volume came out in April 1992 however chapter information stops at Volume 26 with Chapter 137 saying *"(incomplete)"* and with the inconsistent number of chapters per volume it's hard to extrapolate how many chapters there was by Volume 35. this relates to the Japanese release

the English Release appears to have more chapters per volume with Volume 5 ending at *Chapter 44 - Gambling Queen*, however judging by the names of chapters in the English version it appears some of the Japanese Chapters were split, such as *Volume 4: Chapter 15 - A Lame Teacher* in the Japanese version appears to match with the English Version's *Chapters 29-31 - The Wacky Professor Part 1-3*. As there are no ISBN numbers for the English Version after Volume 5 one can assume there are no Legal English versions released beyond Volume 5.

On *City Hunter's* Wikipedia Page, inside the right side info box under English publisher it says

> <sup>NA</sup>
>   Gutsoon! Entertainment (incomplete, defunct)

looking at [Gutsoon! Entertainment's Wikipedia Page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gutsoon!_Entertainment) it says

> On March 15, 2004, Gutsoon! announced that they will be placing their Rajin Comics brand on hiatus. **Raijin Comics ceased publication with its July 2004 issue (issue #46) and the Raijin Graphic Novels line was subsequently cancelled as well.**

this is also confirmed on *City Hunter's* Wikipedia Page

> Attempts were made to license the series for the American comic market during the 1980s; however, Hojo insisted the manga should be released in the right-to-left format. In 2002 Coamix created an American subsidiary, Gutsoon! Entertainment. City Hunter was a flagship title in their Raijin Comics Anthology. Raijin switched from a weekly format to a monthly format before being cancelled after 46 issues.

In these magazine serializations in Japan a Manga Series is generally released a chapter at a time in each issue so the 44 Chapters of the English Version run close to the 46 Issues of *Raijin Comics*

As for other countries there doesn't seem to be any data for their release however the Wikipedia page may only be detailing the original Japanese release and English because it itself is in English as [Anime News Network](https://www.animenewsnetwork.com/encyclopedia/manga.php?id=1593) list other countries that the manga series has been published in, however as i don't know any other languages getting data from another Language's Wikipedia will be a bit harder.

From the data we have on Wikipedia for *City Hunter* we can say that only up to *Volume 5: Chapter 22 - The Game's Queen* was officially localized in English as *Chapter 44 - Gambling Queen*. any other chapters in english that are floating around on the internet i would suspect to be scanlations.

scanlation status is not on topic here on Anime and Manga as such you probably wont find any information here as to any announcement by the scanlation circle why they have stopped, however possible reasons could be due to

- Lack of access to the Raw Japanese Manga
- Lack of Staff (scanlation circles shouldn't be profiting so the staff only works when they have the time)
- Being told to stop by the publishers/mangaka (has happened if i recall, just not sure on the title)
- Just a lack of interest in the series, this can be combined with Lack of Staff as Staff can leave individually when they lack interest.

Answer (score 0):

It's available in Italian up to chapter 193, the full series. It's also available in French. The Italian version has the advantage of being quite cheap to buy, so I highly recommend you to do so you should be able to find it at any online bookshop, and when in doubt, amazon.it or amazon.fr may do the trick. I understand much of Italian being Spanish, so I could read it using the dictionary from time to time. If you don't know any Latin-based language, though, this may not help you, but at least Italian would be easier to understand than Japanese.

Comment: By online, cite a specific publisher/website. If it's an unofficial translations/scanlations, then you are not allowed to put it here as this site does not and will never support piracy. I would suggest revising your answer to include legal sources without duplicating information already mentioned in the previous answer.